# Dask Distributed: Reading .csv from HDFS

Tags: python, hdfs, dask, dask-distributed

I'm performance testing Dask using ["Distributed Pandas on a Cluster with Dask DataFrames"](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/01/12/dask-dataframes) as a guide.

In Matthew's example, he has a 20GB file and 64 workers (8 physical nodes).

In my case, I have a 82GB file and 288 workers (12 physical nodes; there's a HDFS data node on each).

On all 12 nodes, I can access HDFS and execute a simple Python script that displays info on a file:

```
import pyarrow as pa
fs = pa.hdfs.connect([url], 8022)
print(str(fs.info('/path/to/file.csv')))
```

If I create a single-node cluster (only 24 workers) using only the machine running Dask Scheduler, I can read the .csv from HDFS and print the length:

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
dask.config.set(hdfs_backend='pyarrow')
df = dd.read_csv('hdfs://[url]:8022/path/to/file.csv')
df = client.persist(df)
print(str(len(df)))
```

That last line gives 1046250873 (nice!) and takes 3m17s to run.

However, when I use the full cluster, that last line calling `len(df)` dies and I get this error:

> KilledWorker: ("('pandas_read_text-read-block-from-delayed-9ad3beb62f0aea4a07005d5c98749d7e', 1201)", 'tcp://[url]:42866')

This is similar to an issue mentioned [here](https://github.com/dask/dask-yarn/issues/20) which has a solution [here](https://github.com/dask/dask-yarn/pull/30) involving Dask Yarn and a config (?) that looks like: `worker_env={'ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR': ...}`

However, I'm not using Yarn, although my guess is that the Dask Workers are somehow not configured with the HDFS/Arrow paths they need in order to connect.

I don't see any documentation on this, hence my question as to what I'm missing.

**Edit:**

Here's the error traceback I'm seeing in the output of the Dask Workers:

```
distributed.protocol.pickle - INFO - Failed to deserialize b'\x80\x04\x95N\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x8c\x14dask.dataframe.utils\x94\x8c\ncheck_meta\x94\x93\x94(\x8c\x12dask
.compatibility\x94\x8c\x05apply\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x15dask.dataframe.io.csv\x94\x8c\x10pandas_read_text\x94\x93\x94]\x94(\x8c\x11pandas.io.parsers\x94\x8c\x08read_csv\x94\x93\x94(
\x8c\x0fdask.bytes.core\x94\x8c\x14read_block_from_file\x94\x93\x94h\r\x8c\x08OpenFile\x94\x93\x94(\x8c\x12dask.bytes.pyarrow\x94\x8c\x17PyArrowHadoopFileSystem\x94\x93\x94)\x8
1\x94}\x94(\x8c\x02fs\x94\x8c\x0cpyarrow.hdfs\x94\x8c\x10HadoopFileSystem\x94\x93\x94(\x8c\r10.255.200.91\x94MV\x1fNN\x8c\x07libhdfs\x94Nt\x94R\x94\x8c\x08protocol\x94\x8c\x04h
dfs\x94ub\x8c\x1a/path/to/file.csv\x94\x8c\x02rb\x94NNNt\x94R\x94K\x00J\x00\x90\xd0\x03C\x01\n\x94t\x94C\x12animal,weight,age\n\x94\x8c\x08builtins\x94\x8c\x04dict\x94
\x93\x94]\x94\x86\x94h*]\x94(]\x94(\x8c\x06animal\x94\x8c\x05numpy\x94\x8c\x05dtype\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x02O8\x94K\x00K\x01\x87\x94R\x94(K\x03\x8c\x01|\x94NNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff
\xff\xff\xffK?t\x94be]\x94(\x8c\x06weight\x94h2\x8c\x02i8\x94K\x00K\x01\x87\x94R\x94(K\x03\x8c\x01<\x94NNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00t\x94be]\x94(\x8c\x03age\x94h<e
e\x86\x94]\x94(h/h9h@eeh*]\x94(]\x94(\x8c\x0cwrite_header\x94\x89e]\x94(\x8c\x07enforce\x94\x89e]\x94(\x8c\x04path\x94Nee\x86\x94t\x94\x8c\x11pandas.core.frame\x94\x8c\tDataFra
me\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94}\x94(\x8c\x05_data\x94\x8c\x15pandas.core.internals\x94\x8c\x0cBlockManager\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94(]\x94(\x8c\x18pandas.core.indexes.base\x94\x8c\n_new_In
dex\x94\x93\x94hW\x8c\x05Index\x94\x93\x94}\x94(\x8c\x04data\x94\x8c\x15numpy.core.multiarray\x94\x8c\x0c_reconstruct\x94\x93\x94h0\x8c\x07ndarray\x94\x93\x94K\x00\x85\x94C\x01
b\x94\x87\x94R\x94(K\x01K\x03\x85\x94h5\x89]\x94(h/h9h@et\x94b\x8c\x04name\x94Nu\x86\x94R\x94hY\x8c\x19pandas.core.indexes.range\x94\x8c\nRangeIndex\x94\x93\x94}\x94(hjN\x8c\x0
5start\x94K\x00\x8c\x04stop\x94K\x00\x8c\x04step\x94K\x01u\x86\x94R\x94e]\x94(h`hbK\x00\x85\x94hd\x87\x94R\x94(K\x01K\x02K\x00\x86\x94h<\x89C\x00\x94t\x94bh`hbK\x00\x85\x94hd\x
87\x94R\x94(K\x01K\x01K\x00\x86\x94h5\x89]\x94t\x94be]\x94(hYh[}\x94(h]h`hbK\x00\x85\x94hd\x87\x94R\x94(K\x01K\x02\x85\x94h5\x89]\x94(h9h@et\x94bhjNu\x86\x94R\x94hYh[}\x94(h]h`
hbK\x00\x85\x94hd\x87\x94R\x94(K\x01K\x01\x85\x94h5\x89]\x94h/at\x94bhjNu\x86\x94R\x94e}\x94\x8c\x060.14.1\x94}\x94(\x8c\x04axes\x94hV\x8c\x06blocks\x94]\x94(}\x94(\x8c\x06valu
es\x94hy\x8c\x08mgr_locs\x94h(\x8c\x05slice\x94\x93\x94K\x01K\x03K\x01\x87\x94R\x94u}\x94(h\x9dh\x7fh\x9eh\xa0K\x00K\x01K\x01\x87\x94R\x94ueust\x94b\x8c\x04_typ\x94\x8c\tdatafr
ame\x94\x8c\t_metadata\x94]\x94ub\x8c\x0cfrom_delayed\x94t\x94.'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py", line 59, in loads
    return pickle.loads(x)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/hdfs.py", line 38, in __init__
    self._connect(host, port, user, kerb_ticket, driver, extra_conf)
  File "pyarrow/io-hdfs.pxi", line 89, in pyarrow.lib.HadoopFileSystem._connect
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 83, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowIOError: Unable to load libjvm
```

Again, I can use pyarrow to read a successfully read a file from HDFS from any of the 12 nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ho boy! After building libhdfs3 from scratch and deploying to part of the cluster and finding the same exact result (`ImportError: Can not find the shared library: libhdfs3.so`), I realized the issue is I've been starting the Dask workers via `pssh` so they aren't catching the environment variables they should.

Comment: I am trying to run 8gb csv file in cluster. I am getting error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hadoop': 'hadoop'". pyarrow is already installed and hdfs3 is also installed. Please tell stepwise how you are able to read_csv execute csv in worker from client. Worker and client is on different laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the traceback my guess is that PyArrow isn't correctly installed on the worker nodes.  I might ask on the PyArrow issue tracker to see if they can help you to diagnose that traceback.